# Bing and DuckDuckGo have suddenly stopped indexing my website

Tags: seo, search-engine-indexing, noindex

Until a month or two ago Bing and DuckDuckGo were returning search engine results for my website. I've just realised that this is no longer the case. Worse, neither can even find my website when I search for the URL ([www.example.co.uk](http://www.example.co.uk)).

What's going on?

How has it gone from my site ranking highly in my key words, to not even being indexed?

I don't believe I've changed anything on my website. Google still indexes and ranks my site.

It's as if someone has put a noindex on my site.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Signup for Bing Webmaster Tools: https://www.bing.com/webmasters/

Once you verify your site, you can access a lot of troubleshooting tools that will help you determine if there's anything wrong.

Common culprits may include:

- Headers misconfigurations
- Invalid robots.txt
- Malware detected on your site
- Bing Bot being blocked

Comment: My web host found that the Bing Bot was being blocked by security